# Having to implement a generic less than and greater than operation

Tags: c#, generics

I absolutely CANNOT hard code a data type. I need strict data typing. I have to use TValue a <= TValue b. Again, there is ABSOLUTELY NO way to do something like (double) a. This is part of an essential library implementation. The only thing that is specific about the generic values is that they are of static types. IComparable and other interfaces don't seem to work.

Comment: You gave a +1 whilst also admitting you don't know what the question was? :-)

Answer (score 60):

Why doesn't IComparable work for you?

You may not get the syntactic sugar of using the "<" and ">" symbols, but you can check to see if the result of CompareTo is less than or greater than 0, which gives you the same information.

You could even write a nice extension method to make it easier to work with.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(1.IsGreaterThan(2));
    Console.WriteLine(1.IsLessThan(2));
}

public static bool IsGreaterThan<T>(this T value, T other) where T : IComparable
{
    return value.CompareTo(other) > 0;
}

public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this T value, T other) where T : IComparable
{
    return value.CompareTo(other) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Or constrain to `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Building generic classes about ranges of values, this is pure gold. Thanks !

Answer (score 24):

Just use `System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x,y)` - and look for negative, positive and 0 return values.

This supports both `IComparable<T>` and `IComparable`, and works for classes, structs and `Nullable<T>`-of-structs.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2010 Beta, and Intellisense didn't seem to recognize this situation. Very odd behavior.

Comment: @gabe: they are a shorthand way of writing "positive" and "negative".

Comment: It seems like `<0` and `>0` are both shorter and more intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Can you be more precise with your data type(s) and use case?

After all, to implement a comparison operation you will need some sort of information on the class; a fully generic implementation generally wonn't have the information needed to compare two objects - unless you want to sort them on GetHashCode() or ToString(), which is quite an odd thing to do.

There are various generic interfaces intended for type-safe comparison:

- [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) on the objects themselves
- [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) as an external comparison implementation.

If you've implemented `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` on your type, then you can use `Comparer<T>.Default` to get the latter variant automatically - which makes comparison consumers a little shorter to write, and is an alternative for a generic constraint requiring the type to be `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: +1 for explaining what `Comparer<T>.Default` does, and when that is useful.