# Need to Compare Two Generic Objects Using Greater Than or Less Than

Tags: c#, comparison

**Synopsis:** I have a need to take two generic C# objects, and if they are numerical, compare them using either less than or greater than comparisons.

**Problem**: I can't figure out how to have my class implement IComparable as described in this post: [Having to implement a generic less than and greater than operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357410/having-to-implement-a-generic-less-than-and-greater-than-operation).  If that's not even the proper path to take, then I need to know that as well.

**Background:** I have implemented the RequiredIf ValidationAttribute found at [A more complex custom validator](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) but needed the > and < options in addition to an equals comparison.

**Code** (taken from [A more complex custom validator](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2), one-third down the page):

```
private bool IsRequired(object actualPropertyValue)
{
  switch (Comparison)
  {
    case Comparison.IsLessThan:
    case Comparison.IsLessThanOrEqualTo:
    case Comparison.IsGreaterThan:
    case Comparison.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
      if (!Value.IsNumber())
      {
        throw new Exception("The selected comparison option is only applicable to numeric values");
      }
      break;
  }

  switch (Comparison)
  {
    case Comparison.IsNotEqualTo:
      return actualPropertyValue == null || !actualPropertyValue.Equals(Value);
    case Comparison.IsEqualTo:
      return actualPropertyValue != null && actualPropertyValue.Equals(Value);
    case Comparison.IsGreaterThan:
      // THIS LINE FAILS BECAUSE actualPropertyValue DOESN'T IMPLEMENT IComparable 
      return actualPropertyValue != null && (actualPropertyValue.CompareTo(Value) > 0); 
    // The rest of the comparison cases go here...
    default:
      throw new Exception("Comparison value is not defined");
  }
}
```

**Static Helper Extensions:**

```
public static bool IsNumber(this object value)
{
  if (value is sbyte) return true;
  if (value is byte) return true;
  if (value is short) return true;
  if (value is ushort) return true;
  if (value is int) return true;
  if (value is uint) return true;
  if (value is long) return true;
  if (value is ulong) return true;
  if (value is float) return true;
  if (value is double) return true;
  if (value is decimal) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like you should just be able to cast `actualPropertyValue` to `IComparable`:

```
IComparable comparable = (IComparable) actualPropertyValue;
return comparable != null && comparable.CompareTo(Value) > 0;
```

Note that your use of the word "generic" is curious here. If you *actually* made it generic, you could write:

```
private bool IsRequired<T>(T actualPropertyValue) where T : IComparable
```

Then you wouldn't need the cast.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I tried your second option and it seems to compile, so I'll continue to test that.  However, when I implemented it, ReSharper warns me that the `actualPropertyValue == null` statements have a "possible compare of value type with null".  Can that warning be disregarded?  Secondly, based on the link that I am referencing, isn't it true that I am dealing with "generic" objects, or am I using the wrong terminology?

Answer (score 4):

```
int MyCompare (object a, object b)
{
   var ac = a as IComparable;
   var bc = b as IComparable;

    if (ac == null || bc == null)
       throw new NotSupportedException();

    return ac.CompareTo(bc);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, but shouldn't the return line be `return ac.CompareTo(bc);`?

Comment: Richard, I actually used Jon's method, but I'm keeping yours as a nice extension method for quick comparisons.  Thanks for the help!