# C# Template for int and float

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I have two classes, one used for float and one used for int. Their code is exactly the same and I would like to write a template class that would be compatible with both int and float in order not to copy this code with just a different type.

Here is my class :

```
namespace XXX.Schema
{
    public abstract class NumericPropDef< NumericType > : PropDef
        where NumericType : struct, IComparable< NumericType >
    {
        public NumericType? Minimum { get; protected set; }

        public NumericType? Maximum { get; protected set; }

        public NumericType? Default { get; protected set; }

        public NumericPropDef() : base() { }

        public void SetMinimum( NumericType? newMin )
        {
            if( null != newMin && null != Maximum && (NumericType) newMin > (NumericType) Maximum )
                throw new Exception( "Minimum exceeds maximum" );
            Minimum = newMin;
        }

        public void SetMaximum( NumericType? newMax )
        {
            if( null != newMax && null != Minimum && (NumericType) newMax < (NumericType) Minimum )
                throw new Exception( "Maximum is below minimum" );
            Maximum = newMax;
        }

        public void SetDefault( NumericType? def )
        {
            Default = def;
        }
    }
}
```

But for reasons I don't know, I'm getting the following error :

```
error CS0019: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NumericType' and 'NumericType'
```

I'm used to C++ templates, but not to C# templates so I'm a bit lost here. What could be the reason of that ? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357410/having-to-implement-a-generic-less-than-and-greater-than-operation

Comment: Default is `NumericType?` (can be nullable) which is different from `NumericType`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without specifying anything else, any generic parameter (such as your `NumericType`) is assumed to have the same capabilities as [`System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Why? Well, because users of your class *might* pass `System.Object` to the `NumericType` parameter. So, it is not guaranteed that the type passed to that generic parameter supports a `>` operator, and hence the compiler doesn't allow you to use it.

Now, you *have* somewhat restricted `NumericType`, in that you require that any type passed to `NumericType` implement [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and is a structure. However, neither of these restrictions guarantees that there is a `>` operator, so you *still* cannot use it.

In your particular case, you might want to use the [`CompareTo` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx), whose availability on any type passed to `NumericType` *is* guaranteed by your requirement that the type implement `IComparable<T>`. Note, however, that like this, your class can also be used for loads of other types that have nothing to do with numbers, if that poses a problem to you.

In general, your particular quest for finding a restriction that lets users supply a numeric type cannot be properly answered in C#, as numeric types in C# (or the CLI in general) do not inherit from a common base class for numeric types.

Comment: ...and the solution to this issue is to use the `Comparer<NumericType>.Default.Compare` method

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought that IComparable was ensuring the comparison operators were implemented.

Comment: @Virus721: If that were the case, the respective operators would be listed in an operators section in the [docs for `IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Does that provide any advantages over the `CompareTo` method I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the only advantage I can think of is that you don't have to check for `null` (which doesn't apply to structs anyway) - I wrote that comment before you added the `CompareTo` part.